Modifying an environment vairiable when running a Python subprocess
I am attempting to run a Python subprocess in a different virtualenv from the default. I have based my solution on this answer. My script is
import os
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
from icecream import ic

VIRTUAL_ENV = str(Path(Path.home(), '.pyenv/versions/wx'))

script_path = 'scripts/foo'
script_env = os.environ.copy()
script_env["VIRTUAL_ENV"] = VIRTUAL_ENV
ic(os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'])
ic(script_env['VIRTUAL_ENV'])
subprocess.run([script_path], env=script_env)

where foo is a bash script that calls a Python program that requires the virtualenv wx. The script_env['VIRTUAL_ENV'] is correct, however I get the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jeff/projects/scripts/wx_python/wx_python_standard_ids.py", line 1, in 
import wx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'


What gives you that error? What is scripts/foo?

Yws - just realised it does ;( Question changed

maybe you should run /full/path/to/python/in/venv script.py and it should use code from virtualenv

other idea: if you will use shell=True then you can run many commands separated by ; so you could try cd your_folder ; venv/bin/active ; python script.py. Other idea: put these commands in shell/bash script and run this script in Python.

@furas Your comment maybe you should run /full/path/to/python/in/venv script.py and it should use code from virtualenv works. Do you want to work it up into an answer and I will accept

@Psionman How can that work when you say you need to run foo, a bash script? You never mentioned a script.py to begin with (hence my question "what is scripts/foo"...)

Following the suggestion by @furas I realised there is a better way of using the python program to

change the virtualenv
call the script

and that is to call the virualenv directly from the script
Thus I have altered the script so that it uses
subprocess.run([script_path])

python foo.py

becomes
path/to/virtualenv/bin foo.py


This code will activate the virtual environment if it exists and executes the provided script in the environment.
import subprocess
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

def run_subprocess_in_virtualenv(venv_dir, script_path):
    # Construct paths to the virtual environment's Python interpreter
    venv_python = os.path.join(venv_dir, "bin", "python")
    
    # Check if the virtual environment directory exists
    if not Path(venv_dir).is_dir():
        print(f"Virtual environment directory not found: {venv_dir}")
        return
    
    try:
        # Execute the script within the virtual environment
        subprocess.run([venv_python, script_path], check=True)
    
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while running subprocess: {e}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    venv_path = "/path/to/your/virtualenv"
    script = "script.py"
    run_subprocess_in_virtualenv(venv_path, script)


EDIT: Here's a Bash script that will access two environment variables created by the Python script that follows.

PYTHON_VENV_ACTIVATE : The full path to activate the virtual environment
PYTHON_SCRIPT : The path to the Python script to be executed in the virtual environment

Bash script, exec-venv.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Access and use the environment variables passed from Python
echo "Reading environment variables:"
echo "VAR1: $PYTHON_VENV_ACTIVATE"
echo "VAR2: $PYTHON_SCRIPT"

# Activate the virtual environment
source $PYTHON_VENV_ACTIVATE

# Execute Python script
python $PYTHON_SCRIPT

# Deactivate the virtual environment
deactivate

# Exit the script with a successful status code
exit 0

Python script to call the Bash script:
import os
import subprocess

def run_bash_script_with_env_variables(script_path, env_vars):
    # Build the command to execute the Bash script
    command = ["bash", script_path]

    # Create a copy of the current environment and update with additional variables
    env = dict(os.environ)
    env.update(env_vars)

    # Execute the Bash script with the specified environment variables
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, env=env)
    process.communicate()  # Wait for the process to complete

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    script_path = "/path/to/bash/script/exec-venv.sh"
    environment_variables = {
        "PYTHON_VENV_ACTIVATE": "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate",
        "PYTHON_SCRIPT": "/path/to/python/script/script.py"
    }
    run_bash_script_with_env_variables(script_path, environment_variables)


You don't need to explicitly activate if you use venv/bin/python

Virtualenv activation is a shell-only concept. The first source ... command you show here wouldn't affect the subsequent subprocess.run() anyway.

My bad. I've updated the answer with working code.

@DanNagle This works if script is a python program, but in my question foo is a bash script that calls the python program, and it does not work in that case

Edited the answer to include Bash script and Python code to execute it.

This has been answered by this answer
